# Failing to send to $_POST but $_SESSION says something else

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, post

I do not know what is happening with my code, when I run it, sometimes SESSION says there is an array is stored and sometimes it doesn't. I am using a debugger to check the session. When I use isset($_POST), the return value is always false. I am using ajax to pass an array to php.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['jExam'])){
    $decode = json_decode($_POST['jExam']);
    $_SESSION['receive'] = $decode;
    $product = $_SESSION['receive'];
}
else{
    echo "Failed to hold<br>";
}
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class").click(function(event)){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'example.php';
    var jExample = JSON.stringify(array);
    $.ajax({
        data:{'jExam':jExample},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'example.php'
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Figured out why the arrays are stored into SESSION, once I click on the button that opens the other page, and then type in the page before in the url, the array is stored into the SESSION. Don't know why. Still can't figure out why ajax is not sending to post.

**EDIT 2:**

I created a file that handles the request called handle.php. So the php script on top is added into handle.php instead of the webpage. But I am getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)". The code is still the same on top.

handle.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['jExam'])){
        $decode = json_decode($_POST['jExam']);
        $_SESSION['receive'] = $decode;
        $product = $_SESSION['receive'];
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed to hold<br>";
    }
?>
```

**EDIT 3:**

I am using the ajax to pass an array to php in order to store it into session, in order to use the array in another page. The problem is that the array is not passing into $_POST. What I am hoping is that the array can actually pass so I can use it on another page.

***SOLVED:***

All i did was add a form that has a hidden value. And the value actually post

```
<form id = "postform" action = "cart.php" method = "post">
  <input type = "hidden" id="obj" name="obj" val="">
  <input type = "submit" value = "Show Cart" id = "showcart">
</form>
```

In the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showcart").click(function(){
    var json = JSON.stringify(object)
    $('#obj').val(json);
    $('#obj').submit();
  });
});
```

Thank you for everyone at has answered but hope this helps others.

Comment: The Problem might be caused by your JS. Did you try to do it in vanilla JS?

Comment: Its better to use print_r($_POST); after session start line. And share the result. Also note that for checking session value u must need to refresh page.

Comment: Is example.php the current site, or  the php-File to handle the request?

Comment: example.php is another page, should I create a php-file that handles requests?

Comment: Ok I added a php_File that handles the request, still failed

Comment: wait, which page is that? which page is example.php? And how is your Request-handling file called, so the php file you posted?

Comment: Logic is all wrong....redirect will occur and block remaining code. Ajax will never run. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I created a php file called handle.php to handle the request, like you said. I included handle.php into the example.php. So I added the if(isset()) into handle.php, but I am getting an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)"

Comment: where is error thrown? that code doesn't show here. You seem to have a multitude of problems... process flow being among them

Comment: @charlietfl no errors shown on console, if I took out the handle.php from the webpage, the webpage works fine.

Comment: you just said you had an error ...  I asked where that error is thrown

Comment: You need to edit the question with a proper explanation of exactly what you are expecting this code to do....end to end. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: the error is shown on the page itself, thought you meant on console, the error is in the handle.php

Comment: Well `handle.php` doesn't even exist in the question. This is going to go nowhere fast if you don't start right back at the beginning and explain what is going on here. Little bits and pieces are just going to waste everyone's time. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: why aren't you just posting a form and skip the ajax? What is source of array?

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure if using a form can have a value. Not sure how to explain it but I created a button that has data values in it `button class ="addcart" data-product ="Name" data-value ="17.00">Add to Cart</button><br>`. I use the data-product and data-value to create a new item. Don't know how to do that in form

Comment: could simply put the json into a hidden field and submit a form and wouldn't need to store in session and wait for next request

Answer (score 0):

If example.php is the php file which handles the request, you need to change your js code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class").click(function(event)){
    event.preventDefault();
    var jExample = JSON.stringify(array);

    $.ajax("example.php", {
        data:{'jExam':jExample},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

And you should add the complete-Parameter if you want to handle the response.

Your mistake is, you are redirecting the page using `window.location.href` before you even send your request. Therefore, your request never gets sent and the PHP-File is called directly instead, not via AJAX, not with the nessecary data. Therefore, you are missing the data in the PHP-File.

Comment: @charlietfl I did so, and that's what I read [there](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Correct me, if I am still wrong, but I dont believe so.

Comment: @charlietfl oh, you are right, I messed up. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: also it does need to be a string

Comment: @charlietfl Ouch, thanks for that one. Don't know, how I missed that.

Comment: @Syntac no the js is not in the php file, I made a separate file for js

Comment: @User9123 I know, these are separate, but you are still making the mistake, I described. We can chat about it, if you want to. And I am quite sure, my solution works. Just remove the `window.location ....` line in your original code, and it should work fine.

Comment: if you throw the redirect into success handler would do what is expected I think

Comment: @Syntac if I remove window.location then how do I open example.php?, ill try to see if it works

Comment: @User9123 okay, we are a bit confused about your files. You should have 1. The Webpage, causing AJAX with your javascript and 2. a separate php-File to handle the Request.   
How are these files called? Maybe we could chat, then it may be easier. I'd love to help you, but its not so easy this way. Maybe we could chat?

Comment: @Syntac I have four files, javascript.js that contains all the javascript, handler.php, that handles request, two webpages example.php and starter.php. The starter.php will call a function in javascript.js to add an object to the array, and once the user is done adding objects to the array, the user will call a function that will stringify the array and send it to handler.php using ajax.

Comment: @User9123 okay, and the handler.php is the php-file you've given to us? For what is the example.php used, or isnt it nessecary at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to try and make this setup a bit easier on yourself so here are a few things that can help you simplify this. You may or may not have some of these already done, so disregard anything you already do:

1. Use a config file with concrete defines that you include on 1st-level php files
2. Just pass one `data` field with `json_encode()`
3. Don't send json as a data type, it's not required, troubleshoot first, then if you need to, make it default as the send type
4. Use a `success` function so you can see the return easily
5. Make functions to separate tasks

**/config.php**

*Add all important preferences and add this to each top-level page.*

```
session_start();
define('URL_BASE','http://www.example.com');
define('URL_AJAX',URL_BASE.'/ajax/dispatch.php');
define('FUNCTIONS',__DIR__.'/functions');
```

**Form:**

*Just make one `data` that will send a group of data keys/values.*

```
<button class="cart" data-instructions='<?php echo json_encode(array('name'=>'Whatever','price'=>'17.00','action'=>'add_to_cart')); ?>'>Add to Cart</button>
```

Gives you:

```
<button class="cart" data-instructions='{"name":"Whatever","price":"17.00","action":"add_to_cart"}'>Add to Cart</button>
```

**Ajax:**

*Just send a normal object*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Doing it this way allows for easier access to dynamic
    // clickable content
    $(this).on('click','.cart',function(e)){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get just the one data field with all the data
        var data = $(this).data('instructions');
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            // Use our defined constant for consistency
            // Writes: http://www.example.com/ajax/dispatch.php
            url: '<?php echo URL_AJAX; ?>',
            success: function(response) {
                // Check the console to make sure it's what we expected
                console.log(response);
                // Parse the return
                var dataResp = JSON.parse(response);
                // If there is a fail, show error 
                if(!dataResp.success)
                    alert('Error:'+dataResp.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**/functions/addProduct.php**

*Ideally you would want to use some sort of `ID` or `sku` for the key, not name*

```
// You will want to pass a sku or id here as well
function addProduct($name,$price)
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$name]['name']  = $name;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$name]['price'] = $price;

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$name]['qty']))
            $_SESSION['cart'][$name]['qty'] += 1;
        else
            $_SESSION['cart'][$name]['qty'] = 1;

        return $_SESSION['cart'][$name];
    }
```

**/ajax/dispatcher.php**

*The dispatcher is meant to call actions back only as an AJAX request. Because of the nature of the return mechanism, you can expand it out to return html, or run several commands in a row, or just one, or whatever.*

```
# Add our config file so we have access to consistent prefs
# Remember that the config has session_start() in it, so no need to add that
require_once(realpath(__DIR__.'/../..').'/config.php');
# Set fail as default
$errors['message'] = 'Unknown error';
$errors['success'] = false;
# Since all this page does is receive ajax dispatches, action
# should always be required
if(!isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $errors['message'] = 'Action is require. Invalid request.';
    # Just stop
    die(json_encode($errors));
}
# You can have a series of actions to dispatch here.
switch($_POST['action']) {
    case('add_to_cart'):
        # Include function and execute it
        require_once(FUNCTIONS.'/addProduct.php');
        # You can send back the data for confirmation or whatever...
        $errors['data']    = addProduct($_POST['name'],$_POST['price']);
        $errors['success'] = true;
        $errors['message'] = 'Item added';
        # Stop here unless you want more actions to run
        die(json_encode($errors));
    //You can add more instructions here as cases if you wanted to...
    default:
        die(json_encode($errors));
}
```